# How to hide or show uibutton in UITableviewcell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uibutton

I created a button in uitableviewcell

```
@interface MyMusicLibraryCell : UITableViewCell
{
    IBOutlet UIButton * rangeBtn ;
}
```

In .m file

```
@synthesize rangeBtn;
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code 
        rangeBtn = [[UIButton alloc] init];
        rangeBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [rangeBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"fav_4.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        rangeBtn.frame = CGRectMake(260.0f, 10.0f, 20.0f, 20.0f);
        [self addSubview:rangeBtn];
    }

    return self;
}
```

And I want using rangeBtn and add a addTarget in cellForRowAtIndexPath.how should I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `tag` to the button and you can access the button as following:

```
// initWithStyle
rangeBtn.tag = 1;


// cellForRowAtIndexPath
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: @"cell"];
    UIButton *cellButton = (UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag: 1];

    // add target to the button
    [cellButton addTarget: self action: @selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvent: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}
```

Comment: i trying your code in my project,but it does'nt work!   *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIButton addTarget:action:forControlEvent:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x86a5030'

Comment: Are you sure you are referring to the correct cell ? Also, make sure non of the cell's components has that `tag`.

Comment: ok, i fixed it. change addTarget:self to addTarget:null.   thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Set the rangeBtn.tag to some value (e.g 100).

Then in cellForRowAtIndexPath get reference to the button using:
  btn = [cell viewWithTag:100]

Now you can set the target for that button.